Disable abc suggestions in Visual Studio
While editing a Unity .shader file in Visual Studio 2022, I think I accidentally pressed some keyboard shortcut that enabled this ABC suggestion box:

The box does the following:

Displays a list of auto-complete suggestions generated from the other words in the file.
Highlights the word I am currently typing, and every other place the word appears in the file.
When I type a single or double quote, it adds another one after the caret, even when I'm typing a comment.

A web search for visual studio abc box only turns up results related to Visual Studio Code, but I am not using Visual Studio Code. I think this feature is language-specific, because it only seems to be happening in .shader files.
What is this feature called, and how can I disable it?
